# pyspark code ranking partition question where i did wrong?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rank

I have a dataset df as below:

```
ID date        class
1  2020/01/02   [math,english]
1  2020/01/03   [math,english]
1  2020/01/04   [math,english]
2  2020/01/02   [math,english]
2  2020/01/03   [math,english,art]
2  2020/01/04   [math,english]
2  2020/01/05   [math,english,art]
2  2020/01/06   [math,art]
2  2020/01/07   [math,art] 
2  2020/01/08   [math,english,art]
```

my current code is:

```
 df.withColumn("c_order", rank()\
.over(Window.partitionBy("ID","date")\
.orderBy("class")))\
```

I also tried with dense_rank(), and row_number(), but none of them can provide the desire output.

```
 df.withColumn("c_order", dense_rank()\
.over(Window.partitionBy("ID","date")\
.orderBy("class")))\

 df.withColumn("c_order", row_number()\
.over(Window.partitionBy("ID","date")\
.orderBy("class")))\
```

my current output is like in below:

```
    ID   date        class                c_order
1  2020/01/02   [math,english]           1
1  2020/01/03   [math,english]           1
1  2020/01/04   [math,english]           1
2  2020/01/02   [math,english]           1
2  2020/01/03   [math,english,art]       1
2  2020/01/04   [math,english]           1
2  2020/01/05   [math,english,art]       1
2  2020/01/06   [math,art]               1
2  2020/01/07   [math,art]               1
2  2020/01/08   [math,english,art]       1
```

I want the output as below

```
ID   date        class                c_order
1  2020/01/02   [math,english]           1
1  2020/01/03   [math,english]           1
1  2020/01/04   [math,english]           1
2  2020/01/02   [math,english]           1
2  2020/01/03   [math,english,art]       2
2  2020/01/04   [math,english]           3
2  2020/01/05   [math,english,art]       4
2  2020/01/06   [math,art]               5
2  2020/01/07   [math,art]               5
2  2020/01/08   [math,english,art]       6
```

the order only increase if the class is change.
any idea where i did wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post *all* of your code, not just the code for a singular segment.

Comment: what do you mean all of my code? like also for create table for example data??

Comment: I mean ALL your code. The more provided, the more we will be able to help. Don't worry, a long post isn't a bad post if all the information making it long is good/important.

Comment: i just edited and add more, is it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just do a rank. You need to compare with the previous row (using `lag`) to check when the class has changed.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'diff',
    F.coalesce(
        F.col('class') != F.lag('class').over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('date')), 
        F.lit(False)
    ).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'c_order',
    F.sum('diff').over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('date')) + 1
)

df2.show()
+---+----------+------------------+----+-------+
| ID|      date|             class|diff|c_order|
+---+----------+------------------+----+-------+
|  1|2020/01/02|    [math,english]|   0|      1|
|  1|2020/01/03|    [math,english]|   0|      1|
|  1|2020/01/04|    [math,english]|   0|      1|
|  2|2020/01/02|    [math,english]|   0|      1|
|  2|2020/01/03|[math,english,art]|   1|      2|
|  2|2020/01/04|    [math,english]|   1|      3|
|  2|2020/01/05|[math,english,art]|   1|      4|
|  2|2020/01/06|        [math,art]|   1|      5|
|  2|2020/01/07|        [math,art]|   0|      5|
|  2|2020/01/08|[math,english,art]|   1|      6|
+---+----------+------------------+----+-------+
```